# Resize div on browser resize

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a `<div>` which I want to display full screen, but I also need to incorporate a `60px` high `<div>` and a `10px` high `<div>` at the top of the document. The size of the main div will need to re-size as the browser window is re-sized to keep it full screen.

```
<div id="div1" style="height: 60px">

</div>

<div id="div2" style="height: 10px">

</div>

<div id="fullscreen">

</div>
```

So:

fullscreen height = `document size - (#div1 + #div2)`

On re-size recalculate the above value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to achieve this in some cases via just HTML and CSS is to have absolutely positioned div with it's top set to the `70px` and every other direction set to `0px`. Then every other side will adjust itself to the edges of the browser window.

For example:

```
<style type="text/css">
#fullscreen {
    background-color: #0000FF;
    position: absolute;
    top: 70px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
}
</style>

<div id="fullscreen">The Full Screen</div>
```

Comment: This approach performs better and is more maintainable than the jquery approach.  Use this!

Comment: note that you may need rules such as `body{width:100%; height:100%;}` for this to work as expected.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  $('#fullscreen').height($(document).height() - ($('#div1').height() + $('#div2').height()) + 'px');
});
```

**Updated Based On Comment:**

I am using the **[jQuery](http://jquery.com/)** in above code, you will have to download and include it in your page first.

Once you have downloaded and included in your page, then use this code:

```
$(function(){
    $(window).resize(function(){
      $('#fullscreen').height($(document).height() - ($('#div1').height() + $('#div2').height()) + 'px');
    });
});
```

Comment: No need for the 'px' at the end as the `height` function treats numbers to mean pixels.