# html/css: making map 100% height for any monitor

Tags: html, css, dictionary

So I have this map I am trying to configure so that it takes the height of any monitor it displays on:

http://www6.luc.edu/test/cabplan/maps/index2.html

All the CSS is in the file, I have tried height 100% (that erases it completely), I tried position absolute (that throws the map over the top banner), I tried min-height with height 100% (it just takes the min-height). I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Also in the code the map shows that its 895 by 400, which is weird cause it does not look 895px, which I increase using Firebug it grows to the left but I cannot move the map left. I have tried float left, margin 0, margin-left 0 but nothing happens.

Can anyone help me with the HTML/CSS edits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this thread:
[Resize div on browser resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720310/resize-div-on-browser-resize)

Be sure you are setting your body and html to 100% height as well.

With the footer involved, you will set the bottom property to the height of your footer.

Comment: Ok I am definitely making progress but for some reason there is a big gap at the bottom of my map site, here is my test site: http://www6.luc.edu/test/cabplan/maps/index2.html and here is the site I am trying to replicate: http://map.harvard.edu/, i colored the background of my map area to show the gap at the bottom

Comment: Hey, did some messing around with your page.  If you set position:relative on your div that is the child of main_content, it will fall into place.

<div id="main-content">
  
   <div dojotype="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" design="headline" gutters="false"
    style="width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; position: relative;">

      <div id="map" dojotype="dijit.layout.ContentPane" region="center" style="overflow:visible">
      </div>

    </div>
    
</div>

Comment: Wow absolutely works, thanks so much for helping, even with all my expertise in HTML/CSS there always quarks when it comes to styling a map, thanks again