# Div height scale to viewport

Tags: java, jquery, html, css

First off, I am a complete noob. Please respond as if teaching this to a 3yr old.

I know this has been asked before but all of the solutions listed in the previous questions don't seem to work for me. I'm sure its something I am doing wrong but I can't figure it out.

I am using the 3column Holy Grail layout by Matthew James Taylor. http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/ultimate-3-column-holy-grail-ems.htm
(props and thanks for this!)

Viewing source you can see the div structure he used to create the page, mine are identical. I am trying to make it so that ".col2"(".holygrail .col2" in the css) is resized to the viewport minus(-) header&footer.

I have tried using solutions listed in these questions.

[Resize div on browser resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720310/resize-div-on-browser-resize)

[How to change height div on window resize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758651/how-to-change-height-div-on-window-resize)

I realize those solutions are using jquery and I did open it on my page. The compressed version is in the home folder.

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(window).resize(function() {
$('.col2').css('height', window.innerHeight+'px');
});
</script>
</body>
```

The above does not seem to work for me.
I have not tried to adjust it for the header/footer, just tried to call the element, and have had no such luck. I can't seem to call any div, not sure what is wrong.

I have had no luck adapting solutions to fit my need. Again I am sure its something silly, but a little help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/chanckjh/mjQs9/

jquery:

```
$(function() {
    var $height = $(window).height();
    $('.window').css('height', $height +'px');
});​
```

Comment: I do not understand how you are suggesting I implement this, sorry I am a noob remember. In your example do i just change the .window to my .col2 and use your jquery example, or do I create a class as shown in the fiddle, and then what, put that into the div I want resized? sorry thanks for trying to help :)

Comment: `$('.class')` this is the element you want to select.

Comment: Yes!!! Thank you so much, I have been struggling with this for last couple hours. Thanks again!!

Comment: no problem. Just hit the green checkmark that this is the answer.

Comment: oops, done now. was so excited i went off coding, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

you have to reference external scripts and inline scripts in different `<script>` tags.

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>

<script>
    $(window).resize(function() {
        $('.col2').css('height', window.innerHeight + 'px');
    });
</script>
```

see http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1 for more information.

> The script may be defined within the contents of the SCRIPT element or in an external file. If the src attribute is not set, user agents must interpret the contents of the element as the script. If the src has a URI value, user agents must ignore the element's contents and retrieve the script via the URI. Note that the charset attribute refers to the character encoding of the script designated by the src attribute; it does not concern the content of the SCRIPT element.

Comment: I edited the script opening as you said, but it had no effect. I assume I am doing something else wrong still.